# Angular using pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

I have the custom pipe which transforms emoji name (like :wink:), into native emoji (like ) so user can see emoji instead of text.

But when a user clicks post message, I need to send text to the backend, not emoji. How can I show emoji inside textarea but send text?

```
        private emojiObj = new Map();

        constructor(private emojiService: EmojiService) {
        emojis.forEach((el) => {
        this.emojiObj.set(el.shortName, el.unified);
      })  

       transform(value: any): any {

    if (!value.length) {

      return '';
    } else {

      return this.match(value);
    }
  }

  match(value: any): any {
    const findShortNames = new RegExp(':(.*?):', 'g');

    if (value.match(findShortNames)) {

      return value.replace(findShortNames, this.emojiService.unifiedToNative(this.emojiObj.get(Array.from(value.matchAll(findShortNames))[0][1])));
    } else {

      return value;
    }
```

Comment: So where is the actual pipe? A pipe should not be able to modify the source data. You should only return a new formatted value.

Comment: Here is my questions, how to return new formatted value, but do not modify the source data ?